# Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonString' to type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonBoolean'

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I am getting an error: "Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonString' to type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonBoolean'."

Here is Code 1:

```
var json = "{ 'foo': 'bar' }";
var document = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(json);
```

Here is Code 2 with a different method:

```
var json = "{ 'foo': 'bar' }";
var document = new BsonDocument();
document.AddRange(BsonDocument.Parse(json));
```

I am using MongoCSharpDriver v2.1. Can anyone assist?

Comment: Both Code 1 and 2 worked in my computer. Which one did you get the error?

Comment: Encountered same problem, seems to be MongoDb c# driver bug